# Setting up mateusjunges/laravel-kafka with AWS MSK cluster

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, librdkafka, rust-rdkafka

I have defined the KAFKA_BROKERS key value with the aws broker string and specified the AWS AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in the .env but when running the application, I am receiving the below error message:

> "Your message could not be published. Flush returned with error code
> -185: 'Local: Timed out"

and here's my sample code

any suggestions?

```
   $message = new Message( headers: [], body: ['id' => '1212121']);

   Kafka::publishOn(
       'boot-xxxxxxxx.c3.kafka-serverless.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:9098',
       'MSKTutorialTopic'
       )
       ->withMessage($message)
       ->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering what arguments you are trying to use with `publishOn` method. The method signature is

```
/**
...
 * @method static CanProduceMessages publishOn(string $topic, string $broker = null)
...
*/
```

The code that you shared attempts to use AWS host as topic name and topic name as a broker host. Isn't it?